# Let $T: F^2 \rightarrow F^2$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(a_1, a_2)=(a_1 + a_2, a_1)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So we have the question in title, and we have to prove that $T$ is onto and one-one (bijective). So first I try to prove injectivity by proving $T(0)=0$ or proving $T(x)=0\rightarrow x=0$:

$$T(0,0)=(0+0,0)=(0,0)=\mathbf{0}$$

Hence $N(T)={0}$ and $\text{nullity}(t)=0$ we have $T$ as injective. Now using rank-nullity theorem: (Let $T:V \rightarrow W$)
$$\text{nullity}+\text{rank}(T)=\text{dim}(V)$$
Hence we have $$\text{rank}(T)=\text{dim}(V)$$
Given in question:
$$\text{rank}(T)=\text{dim}(W)...(1)$$
Now for definition of being onto function (Analogy from functions: range=codomain)
$$R(T)=W$$
or we can write: $$\text{dim}(R(T))=\text{dim}(W)$$
Using (1): $\text{rank}(T)=\text{span}({R(T)})$
Now putting it back and taking dimension on both sides: $$\text{dim}(R(T))=\text{dim}{(\text{dim}(W))}$$
Hence $$\text{dim}(R(T))=\text{dim}(W)$$
So $T$ is onto
I just want to check if my proof is rigorous and complete/correct enough? If someone can add more to the proof, it will be appreciated.

Comment: "by proving $T(0) = 0$ or proving $T(x) = 0 \to x = 0$": these two are not the same.

Comment: @Trebor Yes thank you, I realised my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the first comment,  you seem to be pretty thoroughly confused about how to prove injectivity (which will in fact solve the entire problem, if you succeed).

Recall that the condition is $T(x)=0\implies x=0.$

So, let's try.   $T(x)=0\implies (x_1+x_2,x_1)=(0,0)\implies x_1+x_2=0\land x_1=0\implies 0+x_2=0\land x_1=0\implies x_1,x_2=0\implies x=0.$

So nothing can be easier and $T$ is in fact injective.

Then by Rank-Nullity we are done,  since  $T:\Bbb F^2\to\Bbb F^2.$